# Converting from Axios to Fetch with Promise.all()

Tags: webpack, es6-promise, polyfills, fetch-api, axios

I am using `Promise.all()` to make a bunch of `axios.get()` calls and ensure that they all return before proceeding, like so:

```
Promise.all([getJSON1(), getJSON2()])
    .then((arr) => {
        var data = {
            json1: arr[0],
            json2: arr[1]
        };

        return data;
    });
```

The functions `getJSON1()` and `getJSON2()` look like:

```
function getJSON1() {
    return axios.get('json1-url.json');
}
```

This is all working fine, however I'm wondering if replacing axios with fetch would reduce the size of my final bundle.js when webpack is done doing its thing.

I'm trying out the [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) and integrating it with webpack in accordance with [this blog](http://mts.io/2015/04/08/webpack-shims-polyfills/), however I'm just not sure how to adjust `getJSON1()` to use fetch. I tried the following:

```
function getJSON1() {
    return fetch('json1-url.json');
}
```

This results in a *TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaulating 'new Promise')*

Comment: Have you tested each fetch call individually? e.g. do `getJSON1()` and `getJSON2()` work ok on their own? Where in your code does the error point to?

Answer (score 0):

> We can call the fetch method like this , hope it may help you:-

```
function getJSON1() {
    return fetch('json1-url.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson;

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```